# Finding parent class using .parent and .hasClass

Tags: jquery, parent

How can I find the parent class of a clicked element?

Currently running this on .`click` event of an element called `.cross`

I want to find the parent classnames:

```
var status = $(this).parent(this).hasClass();
        console.log(status);
```

The code above outputs `false` in the console rather than the classname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I find the parent class of a clicked element?

```
$(this).parent().attr("class")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why your code not works**

`.hasClass()` in jquery is used to find whether the class is present or not in the particular element. So it always return boolean true or false .

**your code be**

In your question you want to get the Parent class so use `.attr()` in jquery. Class is also a one type of attribute in the element

```
var status = $(this).parent().attr('class');
```